# Dataverse - Check if element exists in array returned from OData query using the RetrieveAvailableLanguages function

Tags: dynamics-crm, odata, powerapps, dataverse

I am using the [RetrieveAvailableLanguages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/web-api/retrieveavailablelanguages?view=dynamics-ce-odata-9) function to run this query on my target environment.
`https://ORG_NAME.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.0/RetrieveAvailableLanguages`

In the response from this OData query it should provide one or more language ids to me. Is there some `$filter` query of other OData query that I can append to the end of my API call to check if an element exist in the array that is returned from this API call? I tried some exploration using the [OData In operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/webapi/in-operator), but was not able to check if a certain Id exists in the array using that approach.

```json
{
"@odata.context": "https://ORG_NAME.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.0/$metadata#Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.RetrieveAvailableLanguagesResponse",
    "LocaleIds": [
       3082,
       1033
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`RetrieveAvailableLanguages` is an unbound function and does not have a filter parameter.
Please refer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/webapi/use-web-api-functions#unbound-functions for more information.